# Remove element then add it inside another element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, appendchild, removechild

I would like to remove a `<script>` tag inside a `<div>` and add it to another `<div>`.

In jQuery it would be:

```
$('.scripts').remove().appendTo('.another-container');
```

It works fine in jQuery, but I would prefer to use the plain javascript method than the jQuery one. Therefore I'm trying to write in JS but it doesn't work:

```
const scriptTag = document.querySelector(".scripts");
const container = document.querySelector(".another-container");

for (var i = 0; i < scriptTag.length; i++) {
    scriptTag[i].parentNode.removeChild(scriptTag[i]);
    container.appendChild(scriptTag[i]);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't remove it; just append it. It'll get moved.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but `document.querySelector` doesn't return an array. (`querySelectorAll` does)

```js
const scriptTag = document.querySelector(".scripts");
const container = document.querySelector(".another-container");

scriptTag.parentNode.removeChild(scriptTag);
container.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

However, because nodes can only exist in one place at a time, it would be more concise to just directly append the script tag to the container

```js
const scriptTag = document.querySelector(".scripts");
const container = document.querySelector(".another-container");

container.appendChild(scriptTag); // This will automatically remove scriptTag from its original parent
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to remove the element. It will be removed automatically.

```
const scriptTag = document.querySelector(".scripts");
const container = document.querySelector(".another-container");
container.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Plus, `document.querySelector()` doesn't return an array. So there is no need to `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You must get scriptTag element with querySelectorAll before you use for loop if not it wouldn't work example

```
const scriptTag = document.querySelectorAll(".scripts");
const container = document.querySelector(".another-container");
for (var i = 0; i < scriptTag.length; i++) {
container.appendChild(scriptTag[i]);
scriptTag[i].parentNode.removeChild(scriptTag[i]);
}
```